# Bottom Up MergeSort using Python

Tags: python, mergesort, bottom-up

I've spent countless hours trying to do this. Could anyone point out my mistake?

`a` is just a list, `tmp` is an empty list of size `len(a)`

`z` is basically `len(a)`

`a = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
print 'unsorted:',a
z = len(a)
tmp = range(len(a))`

Here's my sort function:

```
def sort(a,tmp):
        width=1
        while(width<z):
                p=0
                while(p<z):
                        left =p
                        middle = p+width
                        right = p+2*width
                        merge(a,left,middle,right,tmp)
                        p = p+2*width
                t=0        
                while(t<z):
                    a[t]=tmp[t]
                    t=t+1
                width=width*2
                print '\n'
```

and here's merge function :

```
def merge(a,iLeft,iMiddle,iRight,tmp):
        i = iLeft
        j = iMiddle
        k = iLeft
        print iLeft,iMiddle,iRight,'[',i,j,k,']'
        #print i ,j, k,'\n\n'

        while(i<iMiddle or j<iRight):
                if(i<iMiddle and j<iRight):
                        if(a[i]<a[j]):
                                tmp[k]=a[i]
                                i += 1
                                k += 1
                        else:
                                tmp[k]=a[j]
                                j += 1
                                k += 1

                elif (i==iMiddle):
                        tmp[k] = a[j]
                        j += 1
                        k += 1
                elif (j==iRight):
                        tmp[k]= a[i]
                        i += 1
                        k += 1
```

[This Visualization] might help. I still don't know why it's acting this way.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong? Is it the indentation or the looping?

```
Output ::
unsorted: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
0 1 2 [ 0 1 0 ]
2 3 4 [ 2 3 2 ]
4 5 6 [ 4 5 4 ]


0 2 4 [ 0 2 0 ]
4 6 8 [ 4 6 4 ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BUmer.py", line 45, in <module>
    sort(a,tmp)
  File "BUmer.py", line 14, in sort
    merge(a,left,middle,right,tmp)
  File "BUmer.py", line 27, in merge
    if(a[i]<a[j]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[This visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B6,8,33,21,9,8%5D%0Aprint+%27unsorted%3A%27,a%0Az+%3D+len(a%29%0Atmp+%3D+range(len(a%29%29%0Adef+sort(a,tmp%29%3A%0A++++++++width%3D1%0A++++++++while(width%3Cz%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++p%3D0%0A++++++++++++++++while(p%3Cz%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++left+%3Dp%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++middle+%3D+p%2Bwidth%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++right+%3D+p%2B2*width%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++merge(a,left,middle,right,tmp%29%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++p+%3D+p%2B2*width%0A++++++++++++++++t%3D0++++++++%0A++++++++++++++++while(t%3Cz%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++a%5Bt%5D%3Dtmp%5Bt%5D%0A++++++++++++++++++++t%3Dt%2B1%0A++++++++++++++++width%3Dwidth*2%0A++++++++++++++++print+%27%5Cn%27%0Adef+merge(a,iLeft,iMiddle,iRight,tmp%29%3A%0A++++++++i+%3D+iLeft%0A++++++++j+%3D+iMiddle%0A++++++++k+%3D+iLeft%0A++++++++print+iLeft,iMiddle,iRight,%27%5B%27,i,j,k,%27%5D%27%0A++++++++%23print+i+,j,+k,%27%5Cn%5Cn%27%0A+%0A++++++++while(i%3CiMiddle+or+j%3CiRight%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++if(i%3CiMiddle+and+j%3CiRight%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++if(a%5Bi%5D%3Ca%5Bj%5D%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++tmp%5Bk%5D%3Da%5Bi%5D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++i+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++k+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++else%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++tmp%5Bk%5D%3Da%5Bj%5D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++j+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++k+%2B%3D+1%0A+%0A++++++++++++++++elif+(i%3D%3DiMiddle%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++tmp%5Bk%5D+%3D+a%5Bj%5D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++j+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++k+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++elif+(j%3D%3DiRight%29%3A%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++tmp%5Bk%5D%3D+a%5Bi%5D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++i+%2B%3D+1%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++k+%2B%3D+1%0A+%0Asort(a,tmp%29%0Aprint+%27Sorted+Array%3A%27,a&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) may help. I still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: What output are you getting and how is it different from what you expect.

Comment: Z is not defined in your sort function. k is iLeft in your second function but you most likely meant iRight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it was a valiant effort the *primary mistake* you made was with the nested flow control approach -- the human mind can only handle so many nested `while`-loops.  Additionally, the fact that the merge function modifies `a` *in place* makes it extremely difficult to ascertain what is happening.  Even if you have an amazing mind that can keep track of all that action, save that brain energy for tackling the problem rather than flow control!

In general, you want to do your best to keep your program *flat* -- avoid nested flow control.  Additionally, unless you are doing dedicated object-oriented-programming, instead of modifying `a` in place you should attempt to return a specific value.

Here is another approach to mergesort that tries to keep things more flat and explicit:

```
def merge(merged, a, b):

    if a and b:
        return merge(merged + [min(a[0], b[0])],
                     a[1:] if min(a[0], b[0]) == a[0] else a,
                     b[1:] if min(a[0], b[0]) == b[0] and not a[0] == b[0] else b
                     )

    elif a and not b and len(a) > 1:
        return merged + merge([], a[:len(a)/2], a[len(a)/2:])
    elif a and not b:
        return merged + a
    elif b and not a  and len(b) > 1:
        return merged + merge([], b[:len(b)/2], b[len(b)/2:])
    elif b and not a:
        return merged + b
    else:
        return merged

def mergesort(lst):

    if not lst:
        return []
    elif len(lst) == 2:
        return [min(lst), max(lst)]
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst
    else:
        return merge([], mergesort(lst[:len(lst)/2]), mergesort(lst[len(lst)/2:]))
```

This effort to keep things explicit and minimize flow control structures is common in a style of programming known as **functional programming**.  There's a great free book on it that you can access here:

http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/files/functional-programming-python.pdf

Realize this might not be the exact answer you're looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: The python functional programming book you suggested is brilliant. Thanks for that.

I was trying to do the Bottom Up Mergesort without using Recursion. I wrote it in Java and it works fine. Just wondering why it did not work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I feel tired but happy. I stumbled upon the answer by amazing visualization tool on PythonTutor and very keen attention to the mathematics of the iterations.

The program works fine for arrays that are of length = power of 2. 
Everything else gives an array out of index exception. 
I should've implemented a try-except block to handle these things.

Anyway, now I know. Thanks to snakes_on_a_keyboard for the guidance on Functional Programming.

The reason why I'm not revealing any more details to this problem is because snakes_on_a_keyboard already provided a far better and elegant solution.

Comment: Aw shucks :) It's very impressive you were able to pull that off, I don't think I could've done that.  Thanks for the kind words.